# C++ convert string characters lower to upper and upper to lower

Tags: c++, algorithm

Can someone help me to write a few c++ lines of code to convert an input string letters as follow:

> 1. Lowercase letters to Uppercase letters.
> 2. Uppercase letters to lowercase letters.
> 3. libraries functions are not allowed.
> 4. if statement, comparisons, | operation and & not allowed.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you're asking someone to do your homework for you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something no sane person would do. SO is supposed to be about real world problems that you face, not concocted scenarios with bizarre limitations.

Comment: @paxdiablo Concocted scenarios with bizarre limitations would be fine with me if I could only see that someone tried to solve it themselves and failed at some point.

Comment: @hasan i get that, but then you could point out ways you tried and failed. Often those constraints by a teacher are not totally unreasonable and usually they gave hints in class. Personally i have no idea how you could achive this without any if-statements/logical-operators/comparisons.

Comment: It's a friend challenge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write an translation array (= map).

a -> A
A -> a
b -> B
B -> b
...
z -> Z
Z .. z

For ASCII you can implement it as a `char[]` with 128 entries and simply use the character of you source as index to read the resulting character.

```
char translate[128]; 
translate['A']='a';
...
```

Possible Implementation:

```
// The following init-String is quite long (128 characters)!
char* translate="                                                                abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz      ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ     ";
int i=0;
while(0!=s[i])
    s[i] = translate[s[i++]];
```

Comment: Hmm. Pre-coded lookup table. Nice option too... +1

Comment: good idea, probably the most inconvinient way to do this, but it should fit the limitations given, but i really cant see any educational purpose to force students to solve an issue this way.

Comment: un accepted your answer cause its not a few lines of code as I mentioned.

Comment: It can be done in 2 lines of code, actually :) One code is array initialization, second is actual translation.

Comment: @hasan that's not what you asked for, "help me to write a few c++ lines of code" ... Not "help me __by__ writing a few" .. a minor difference...

Comment: @hasan: I added an implementation in 4 lines. (I doubt you will find an answer with less lines of code)

Comment: @hasan: I think the version with more lines is more easy to understand. Reducing lines of code is an optimization not directly related to the question.

Answer (score 3):

If your input is ASCII, you can simply invert bit 5 which means xor the value 32 to each character. That will convert lowercase to upper case and vici versa.

Only problem is it only works for a-zA-Z and nothing else.

Comment: This will be tricky, though, as the bitwise operators `|` and `&` seem to be forbidden by the limitation in point 4.

Comment: Not only does it not work, it breaks the text (space becomes NULL-terminator, etc.)

Comment: @Hulk: XOR is "^" symbol...

Comment: +1 Very cool solution. Still I am curios how you will do a cycle over the string with no comparison ;)

Comment: @DarkWanderer: That is part of what I meant with `Only problem is it only works for a-zA-Z and nothing else.`

Comment: What I mean character comparison. Is there a solution whitout XOR

Comment: @hasan: yes see my other answer using an array and no logic operations.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `std::transform` and the functions `toupper` and `tolower`.

EDIT: sorry missed your last two points. You will have to perform a cycle like for and you may use the ternary operator `?` to avoid if statements. A possible solution for to upcase is:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
  s[i] = (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z') ? s[i] - 'a' + 'A' : s[i];
}
```

Comment: functions not allowed

Comment: that's not allowed too. no comparisons

Comment: @hasan sorry but this sounds a bit too much. Almost anything you write will come down to some comparisons in the end.

Comment: Well, actually XOR solution in another answer does cut it. Can't imagine the academic value of such teching though...

Comment: @DarkWanderer yes I just saw the other answer and I really like it. Will keep mine as it shows kind of approach to make sure you only upcase letters.

Comment: maybe to get advantage of the resources limitations that you have.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work, but only if you have alphabets

```
        char c = 'a';
        int e = c;
        int d = e < 90 ? e + 32 : e - 32;
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution: was looking for others.

```
string s;
cin>>s;
int a[3] = {'A', 'a', 'a'};
int A[3] = {'a', 'A', 'A'};
for (int i=0; i<s.size(); ++i)
    s[i] = s[i] - a[(s[i]-'A')/26] + A[(s[i]-'A')/26];
cout << s << endl;
```

Thanks for trying.

Comment: So at least a comparisons for the loop is still allowed. ;-)

Comment: it's look like that :)